# Db2 max(DATE_FIELD) optimization

Tags: sql, db2

I encountered this SQL statement in our legacy software:
`select max(DATE_FIELD) from schema.VERY_LARGE_TABLE`.

Now, this in itself would not be a problem, but VERY_LARGE_TABLE contains over 20,000,000 records and execution of the statement sometimes exceeds specified timeout of 30 seconds. This now represents an issue as users do not see a correct date.
I have stored this date in cache, so that once the date is obtained it is not obtained any more that day. But this does not help with original issue.

I was wondering, is there a way to optimize a table or SQL statement to perform faster than it does now?

[Edit] This behaviour is also only in place until table is in DB2 server's cache. After that, the query runs in approximately 2 seconds.

[Edit2] The platform is IBM DB2 9.7.6 for LUW.

[Edit3] DDL:

```
create table MYSCHEMA.VERY_LARGE_TABLE (
    ID integer not null generated always as identity (start with 1,
                                                      increment by 1,
                                                      minvalue 1,
                                                      maxvalue 2147483647,
                                                      no cycle,
                                                      cache 20),
    CODE_FIELD varchar(15) not null,
    DATE_FIELD date default CURRENT DATE not null
)
in TS_LARGE;

create unique index MYSCHEMA.VERY_LARGE_TABLE_1 on MYSCHEMA.VERY_LARGE_TABLE (CODE_FIELD asc, DATE_FIELD asc);
create index MYSCHEMA.VERY_LARGE_TABLE_ARCHIVE on MYSCHEMA.VERY_LARGE_TABLE (DATE_FIELD asc, CODE_FIELD asc);
create index MYSCHEMA.INDX_VERY_LARGE_TABLE_ID on MYSCHEMA.VERY_LARGE_TABLE (ID asc);

alter table MYSCHEMA.VERY_LARGE_TABLE add constraint MYSCHEMA.PK_VERY_LARGE_TABLE primary key (CODE_FIELD, DATE_FIELD);
```

Comment: Have you tried to add an index on `DATE_FIELD` ?

Comment: Retagged to `DB2` since that's what you say you're using. `sql-server` is the **Microsoft** SQL Server product (**not** DB2)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson... I have checked with our DBA and index is already set on that field.

Comment: What's this being used for?  Especially since the version you've posted has no conditions (no `WHERE` clause), I'm really suspicious about the need.  There may be a better way to find/use this information.  For example, if this represents, say "last day of sales", but you have a daily sale-report process that aggregates info, just yank it off the sale report (or something).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse... Believe it or not, this is in use only to display a last date the table has been populated with data. Nothing fancy behind it all.

Comment: Which DB2 platform is your server running: DB2 for IBM i, LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows), or z/OS?  They have different features, which may affect how to answer this question.

Comment: @WarrenT - Just edited my question with this information.

Comment: Please post the DDL for the table and index(es).

Comment: I edited my original psot with DDL statement

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can do.

1. Create a index on the `date_filed`
2. Execute the select statement with `with ur` at the end of the statement like 
   `select max(DATE_FIELD) from schema.VERY_LARGE_TABLE with ur` this will speed up the process.
3. Try to increase the primary and secondary logfile sizes but take care to take the help of `DBA` before doing this as this will effect the database, If you are not sure then don't go for this option.
4. If there are bulk operations going on table issue frequent commits.

Comment: 'with ur' only shades off some 0.4 seconds

Comment: This is a platform dependent answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have an index only on DATE_FIELD DESCENDING, then try

```
SELECT DATE_FIELD
  FROM VERY_LARGE_TABLE
  ORDER BY DATE_FIELD DESC
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
  WITH UR
```

Comment: That is 1.2 seconds slower than original statement.